# Space in RewriteCond

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products=Product Name$
RewriteRule ^buyonline\.php$ http://www.example.com/shop/5-Product-Name.html? [L,R=301]
```

I need to redirect links existing in Google already, however there is no pattern so I can't just use e.g. `^products=(.*)$`.

Code above works fine if parameter has no spaces. I have tried lots of combinations like \s doublequotes, etc, etc.

Comment: Most likely the space character will be encoded when the request reaches your server, so try using `%20` in its place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Space is transmitted as `%20` to Apache server and `%` needs to be escaped as well.

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products=Product\%20Name$
RewriteRule ^buyonline\.php$ http://www.example.com/shop/5-Product-Name.html? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I needed to use the regex whitespace character `\s` for matching what I would expect to be a space after MSIE in this user agent test:

    `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*MSIE\s[67](?!.*Trident[1-9]).*$`

Comment: Try this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^.*MSIE [67](?!.*Trident[1-9]).*$"`