# What does it mean ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 an it ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

At the moment I am developing a website with user interaction. I could transform all of the usernames in links for the profile page with a file .htaccess that has the following commands:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1
```

If I understand correctly, this code substitutes the "profile.php" for the argument after the signal "?" if the URL matches the regular expression. But I didn't understood how the "u=$1" accomplishes that because the "u" is not a variable session. This is my configuration in PHP for the session variables:

```
$_SESSION["id"] = $id;
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
$_SESSION["password"] = $pswd;
$_SESSION["email"] = $email;
```

I would like to include too space in the regular expression, because at the moment only usernames like "FirstUser" are accepted, user names like "First User" give me an error at the browser.

When I add a space in the pattern I get the following HTTP 500 error:

[image: Server Error]

Comment: `u` is a `$_GET` variable. `echo $_GET['u']`

Comment: And to get a space just add a space in the pattern

Comment: check the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233615/space-in-rewritecond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` config

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1
```

will *try* to load the [rewrite engine](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine), which may not be allowed (check this part first!) and (if successful) will then take matches under the `.htaccess` file's structure and convert them to `profile.php` with an HTTP [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request using variable `u` set to a value equal to that sub-path.

So if the `.htaccess` file lives at `/home/kasbah/public_html` and corresponds to `http://foobar/~kasbah`, then when a user goes to `http://foobar/~kasbah/it-works`, they will be redirected to `http://foobar/~kasbah/profile.php?u=it-works`.

Your PHP code can then call something like [`$_GET['u']`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) in order to act on that variable.

[Escape spaces as `%20`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233615/space-in-rewritecond/18234338#18234338). You can also make the final `/` optional and have only one `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]|%20)+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1
```